# Update a widget when clicked, if user created multiple widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

My app is an Android widget. It adds a button on home Screen; if a user clicked in this `Button` it will open a window. This window is waiting an user input. It has to write a value and this value will change the text in the `Button`.

The problem is if the user creates many widgets and clicked on the `Button` in any widget and write a value the value will be set only on the last created widget.

How can I make the `Button` change text on his widget?

And this is my code

```
public class Widget_note extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        the_context =  context ;
        the_appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager ;
        the_appWidgetIds = appWidgetIds ;

        Intent open_activity087 = new Intent();
        open_activity087.setClassName("syr.hamza.app.mynotes_v2", "syr.hamza.app.mynotes_v2.SetWidgetValue");
        open_activity087.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(open_activity087); 
        /*this will be open activity Immediately after creating widget to enter a value 
        * and will calling a set_value_in_widget() Function (at Below) with the value 
        * and this don't have any problem*/

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, EditWidgetValue.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds,views);
        /* this will be open activity if clicked on the button and get the value from user
        * and calling set_value_in_widget() Function
        * here is a problem */
    }

    public static Context the_context ;
    public static AppWidgetManager the_appWidgetManager ;
    public static int[] the_appWidgetIds ;

    public static void set_value_in_widget(String value) {

        RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(the_context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views2.setTextViewText( R.id.widget_button , value ) ;
        the_appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(the_appWidgetIds, views2   );   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep all ids after a widget instance creating into SharedPreferences and on the OnUpdate read it from preferences and use instead the_appWidgetIds. Also you will need to remove them from preferences on onDelete.